# Unable to send date as text to datepicker field using send_keys when max attribute is set using ChromeDriver and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to use `chromedriver` to download some files.

I have switched to `chromedriver` because in `firefox` the link I need to click opens a new window and the download dialog box appears even after all the required settings and I wasn't able to get around it.

`chromedriver` works fine for the download but I can't seem to `send_keys()` to the element below, it works on firefox but can't seem to get it to work on this.

```html
<input name="" value="" id="was-returns-reconciliation-report-start-date" type="date" class="was-form-control was-input-date" data-defaultdate="" data-mindate="" data-maxdate="today" data-placeholder="Start Date" max="2020-02-12">
```

I have tried:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id("was-returns-reconciliation-report-start-date")
el.clear()
el.send_keys("2020-02-01")
el.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)  # Separately

# Tried without clear as well
# no error but the date didn't change in the browser

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('was-returns-reconciliation-report-start-date').value = '2020-01-05'")

# No error and no change in the page
```

Comment: Is there an option to click in the `enter` instead of pressing the key? Just to have another approach

Comment: @CeliusStingher I can click the `datepicker` box but it doesn't help as the value doesn't change.

Comment: Do you think I could check the link or is it private?

Comment: @CeliusStingher The link is private, its a corporate after login link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a character sequence to an `<input>` field ideally you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `ID`:

  ```
  el = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "was-returns-reconciliation-report-start-date")))
  el.clear()
  el.send_keys("2020-02-12")
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  el = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.was-form-control.was-input-date#was-returns-reconciliation-report-start-date")))
  el.clear()
  el.send_keys("2020-02-12")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  el = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='was-form-control was-input-date' and @id='was-returns-reconciliation-report-start-date']")))
  el.clear()
  el.send_keys("2020-02-12")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```